# how to mount by UUID without using /etc/fstab

Tags: mount

I am looking for command like

```
mount 1234-SOME-UUID /some/mount/folder
```

I am connecting a couple of external USB hard drives. I want them to be mounted on specific folders during startup. I am unable to boot using `/etc/fstab` if one of the drive is not connected. so I am using an `init` script. But `/dev/sdbx` enumeration is not always same to use with `mount /dev/sdX /some/mount/folder` in the `init` script.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

From the *manpage* of `mount`.

```
-U, --uuid uuid
       Mount the partition that has the specified uuid.
```

---

So your mount command should look like as follows.

```
mount -U 1234-SOME-UUID /some/mount/folder
```

or

```
mount --uuid 1234-SOME-UUID /some/mount/folder
```

A third possibility would be

```
mount UUID=1234-SOME-UUID /some/mount/folder
```

Answer (score 3):

- On DragonFly BSD, you'd use [`/dev/part-by-uuid/`](http://bxr.su/DragonFly/sys/kern/subr_disk.c#disk_probe_slice).
- On Debian GNU/Linux 7.11 (wheezy), `/dev/disk/by-uuid/` is available (which I was able to easily find with [`find /dev -type d`](http://mdoc.su/o/find.1), as the output of `ls -la /dev` didn't seem to have anything relevant).
- On FreeBSD 11.1, `/dev/gptid/` would have you covered (likewise, as per `find /dev -type d`).

---

However, back to your original problem — not every filesystem described within [`fstab(5)`](http://mdoc.su/-/fstab.5) has to be mounted at boot time — just annotate your removal disc within `fstab` with the ***`noauto`*** option, and it won't be mounted during boot (but you could still mount it by path, which would be much easier to manage than having to have UUIDs scattered all over the place).

> [The option “auto” can be used in the “noauto” form to cause a file system not to be mounted automatically (with mount -A or mount -a, or at system boot time).](http://mdoc.su/o/fstab.5)